# Why aren't my forms being called on this form?

Tags: javascript, python, django

Using django atm:

Here are my forms:

```
<form name="chrisForm" action="">
    <input type="text" name="christext">
    <br>
    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' onclick="return chrisFunction()">
    Submit</button>
</form>


<!-- modify the searchwords form -->
<form name="articleForm" action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" placeholder='Modify the keywords' name="searchkeyword">
    <br><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" onclick="return validateForm()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now here is the javascript functions from an external source:

```
    function validateForm() {
        var x = document.forms['articleForm']['searchkeyword'].value;
        if (x == null || x == "") {
            alert("Please enter a search keyword(s)");
            return false
        }
    }

    function chrisFunction() {
        var y = (document.forms['chrisForm']['christext'].value);
        if (y === "1" || y === "2") {
            alert('You have entered 1 or 2, congrats!');
            return false
        }
        else if 
            (y === "" || y === null) {
            window.open('http://forbiddengrounds.net',"", height="200", width="200");
        } 
    }
```

When I click on my buttons it doesn't do anything except it procs the "action" part but it should give an alert when I click the button without putting anything in the text box (or entering 1 or 2 for the chrisFunction)

Comment: remove the `'return'` from your `onclick` properties.

Comment: Thank you it worked

Comment: If the script comes from an external source (different host) it might be restricted by the cross domain security of the browser.